# How to specify a font in latexml?

Tags: fonts, latexml

I would like to convert a tex source to html with latexml while keeping the fonts that pdflatex uses, for example latin modern. Can this be achieved with latexml?

I downloaded the latin modern webfont kit from [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Latin-Modern-Roman) and was able to manually tweak the html output from latexml by adding a reference to the relevant stylesheet and a styles rule applying the font-face to elements. Using this method, I still would have to manually specify each variant of the font (regular, italic, bold, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am one of LaTeXML's developers.

I think your best approach today is to proceed with how you've started - creating a custom CSS theme which specifies the font-face rules with the fonts of your choosing. You could direct the latexmlpost (or latexmlc) executables to use that via the `--css` directive, possibly combined with `--nodefaultcss`, if you no longer require the mainline `LaTeXML.css` and similar assets.

You will likely want to ensure the fonts of your choosing are available to readers, when the assets are served on the web, but that is a process external to latexml. You can consult the way ar5iv has implemented this over latexml-based HTML, as one example.

1. [@font-face declarations for Noto](https://github.com/dginev/ar5iv/blob/main/assets/ar5iv-site.0.2.1.css)
2. [using CSS variables to then specify font-family](https://github.com/dginev/ar5iv-css/blob/main/css/ar5iv.css#L7-L8)

The ar5iv example possibly goes a bit overboard, as it currently micromanages 31 separate rules where the font-family is set.

As to web fonts for Latin Modern, that is not a subject I know much about myself. But a quick search landed on one solution, named [lmweb](https://lalten.github.io/lmweb/) which you could try to incorporate with the "CSS theme" approach.